# Ggplot is not showing up the legend

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have the following graph:

[image]

Which I made using this code below:

```
plot_fig4 <- ggplot(fig4, aes(x=dias))+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=complete_preds_means), span = 0.1, se=FALSE, color="#9a6584", size=1)+
  geom_smooth(aes(y=contrafact), span = 0.1, se=FALSE, colour="#000000", size=1) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=complete_preds_lower, ymax=complete_preds_upper), fill="#9a6584", alpha=0.2)+
  labs(title = "<span style='color: #9a6584;'>Gràfic 2. <span><span style='color: black;'>Evolució del PVPC i de l'estimada sense el topall del gas<span>", 
       y="",
       x="", 
       caption="Font: Hidalgo, M. et al. (2022)") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=seq(from=100, to=900, by=100))+
  scale_x_date(expand = c(0, 0), date_breaks="1 month", date_labels = "%b\n%Y")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=as.numeric(as.Date("2022-06-13")), linetype=2, color=rgb(0,0,0))+   #afegim la línia puntejada negra
  theme_minimal()+
  theme(
    plot.background = element_rect(fill="transparent", colour=NA),
    panel.background = element_rect(fill="transparent", colour=NA),
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.grid.major.y = element_line(color = "grey80"),
    plot.title = element_markdown(hjust=0, size=15, face="bold"),   #element_markdown si el títol té varis colors. 
    plot.caption = element_text(hjust = 0, size=12),
    strip.text.x = element_text(size=15),
    axis.line.x = element_line(color="black"),
    axis.line.y = element_line(color="black"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(size=12),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size=12),
    axis.title.x = element_text(size=10, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=12, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)),
    axis.title.y = element_text(size=10, face="bold",
                                margin = margin(t=0, b= 0, r = 11, l = 5)),
    legend.position = c(5,5),
    legend.text = element_text(size=20))
```

But the legend is not showing up.

Here is a small sample of my data:

```
structure(list(dias = structure(c(19052, 19053, 19054, 19055, 
19056, 19057, 19058, 19059, 19060, 19061, 19062, 19063, 19064, 
19065, 19066, 19067, 19068, 19069, 19070, 19071), class = "Date"), 
    complete_preds_means = c(341.07434, 381.59167, 455.47815, 
    485.05597, 527.60876, 562.63965, 602.48975, 624.663, 626.5637, 
    527.2239, 420.71643, 389.30804, 378.74396, 366.61548, 361.36566, 
    363.37253, 319.31824, 314.39688, 303.60342, 294.8934), contrafact = c(364.5, 
    358.89, 466.64, 470.11, 464.25, 487.27, 591.2, 715.33, 628.02, 
    505.98, 402.9, 316.81, 323.35, 358.61, 354.26, 369.5, 317.01, 
    336.5, 285.33, 270.91), complete_preds_lower = c(320.6368042, 
    361.7870895, 432.4487762, 461.2275833, 503.2255051, 535.7108551, 
    576.3850006, 597.9762146, 601.4407013, 504.0448837, 398.7777023, 
    368.0046799, 356.3603165, 345.5847885, 339.9679932, 342.7514801, 
    298.3247482, 293.4419693, 282.5286865, 275.4635284), complete_preds_upper = c(359.9897186, 
    402.5708664, 477.4746765, 508.7775711, 550.3326447, 587.6521027, 
    628.5320251, 649.9691833, 649.4831665, 547.9886108, 442.046402, 
    410.8121475, 399.0208908, 389.8615128, 387.4929993, 386.2935928, 
    340.140834, 336.3622116, 324.793483, 315.4606934)), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: You need to map a color within `aes` like `geom_smooth(aes(y=complete_preds_means, color = "predicted means")`. Use `scale_color_manual` to set specific colors.

Comment: Hello Maria, the suggestion by @Roland is correct: please post the code with the suggested edit so we can check and see why you're still getting nothing.